# How do I migrate data where source has 2 data directories to a target cluster with just 1?

Tags: cassandra

**Now:**
Single Node
cassandra 3.11.3 + kairosdb 1.2
Two data storage path
/data/cassandra/data/kairosdb    4T    Old data
/data1/cassandra/data/kaiosdb    1.1T  Now Wrting data

**target:**
Three Node
cassandra 3.11.3 + kairosdb 1.2
One data storage path
/data/cassandra/data/kairosdb

In this case, how to migrate the data in two data directories under a single node to a three-node cluster, each node of this three-node cluster has only one data directory

I understand how to do it (and have practiced it) when migrating a single node to a three-node cluster, but only when there is only one data directory.2 data directories are migrated to 1,I have searched the Internet for a long time, but there is no reference material.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Data directories are something that the individual Cassandra node cares about but the Cluster doesn't.
Usually you'd want to have all nodes share the same configuration but *for replication it really doesn't matter where the SSTables are on Disk on each node*.

So migrating here would be the same as you've practiced.

That said the process I'd choose would be to add the new nodes as a second DC with the right replication, run a repair to have all the data in sync and then decommission the original node.

Answer (score 0):

When cloning application data to a new cluster, the configuration of the source cluster is mostly irrelevant. What is important is that (a) you know which application tables you need to migrate, and (b) the directories where they are located.

Specifically for your situation, there are two options available to you:

1. the file copy method, and
2. the bulk-load method.

#### File copy method

**WARNING** - This method will only work if the application keyspace(s) have a replication factor of 3. Otherwise, you can only use the bulk-load method.

The high level steps to copy the application data from the source node to the target nodes are:

1. Take a snapshot of the first application table.
2. Create the table schema on the target cluster.
3. Copy the data files (via SCP, FTP, etc) from the source node to the *corresponding* table sub-directory on the three target nodes.
4. Run the `nodetool refresh` command on the target nodes.

Repeat the steps above for each application table you need to clone.

For details, see the procedure I documented in [How to restore snapshots to another Cassandra cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316497/).

#### Bulk-load method

The high-level steps for bulk-loading application data to the target cluster are:

1. Take a snapshot of the first application table.
2. Bulk-load the data to the target cluster using the `sstableloader` utility.
3. Repeat the steps above until all application tables have been cloned to the target cluster.

For details, see the procedure I documented in [How to migrate data to a new Cassandra cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316520/). Cheers!